# python How to make timeit recognize defined inputs

Tags: python, pandas, timeit

I have a df defined that I am successfully running operations on. I want to time the difference between iterative `for` loops and vectorized operations. I have read various examples of how to use timeit, but when I try them I am getting the errors below. What am I doing wrong?

Imports:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import timeit
```

This loop works:

```
for u in df['owner'].unique():
    print(u, ': ', len(df[(df['owner'] == u)]), sep = '')
```

But when I try to time it like so ...:

```
s = """\
for u in df['owner'].unique():
    print(u, ': ', len(df[(df['owner'] == u)]), sep = '')"""

time_iter_1_1_1 = timeit.timeit(s)
```

... it produces this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-7526e96d565c> in <module>()
      3 #     print(u, ': ', len(df[(df['owner'] == u)]), sep = '')""")
      4 
----> 5 time_iter_1_1_1 = timeit.timeit(s)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\timeit.py in timeit(stmt, setup, timer, number, globals)
    231            number=default_number, globals=None):
    232     """Convenience function to create Timer object and call timeit method."""
--> 233     return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
    234 
    235 def repeat(stmt="pass", setup="pass", timer=default_timer,

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\timeit.py in timeit(self, number)
    176         gc.disable()
    177         try:
--> 178             timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    179         finally:
    180             if gcold:

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\timeit.py in inner(_it, _timer)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

And when I try this ...:

```
time_iter_1_1_1 = timeit.timeit(
"""for u in df['owner'].unique():
    print(u, ': ', len(df[(df['owner'] == u)]), sep = '')""")
```

... I get this error:

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 57))

...

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

The df is defined and working. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm running python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, either

1. Pass an argument `globals` that allows `timeit` to resolve the name,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
timeit.timeit(statement, globals={'df': df}) # globals=globals()
```

---

2. ...Or, pass a string argument `setup` that sets up `df` for you.

```
timeit.timeit(statement, setup='import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame(...)')
```

Comment: Thank you, coldspeed, the `globals()` parameter works great:  

`time_iter_1_1_1 = timeit.timeit(s, globals={'df': df})`  

It is printing the output (700 lines) multiple times (currently on the 5th pass, I think). I assume this is because it returns a "best of" time of several runs. Still waiting to see the final result.

Comment: coldspeed, I spoke too soon. While passing `globals` allows the `timeit` function to run, it is simply repeating endlessly and never ending. I tried it with a `df` with just 6 rows of data and it repeats thousands of times as if it's in an endless loop. Any ideas?

Comment: @KarlBaker Pass a `numbers` argument: `number=30` (or whatever you find appropriate). The resultant timeit is the total time for X runs, whatever X is you pass.

Comment: with the number arg I'm getting an error at the very end. It runs correctly through `s` 2 times, but then throws an error. Any ideas?  

`time_iter_1_1_1 = min(timeit.timeit(s, `  
`setup = setup,`  
`----> number = 2))`  
`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: I got it to work using `globals` instead of `setup`: `time_iter_1_1_1 = timeit.timeit(s, globals={'df': df}, number = 1)`